# Unable to redirect to '/' with replace in onEnter hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, react-router

I have these two methods:

```
  toLogin: function (nextState, replace) {
    if (!localStorage.get("token")) {
      return replace('/signin');
    }
  },
  toHome: function (nextState, replace) {
    if (localStorage.get("token")) {
      return replace('/');
    }
  }
```

`return replace('/signin')` is working like charm but `return replace('/')` gives me that error:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http:' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000'.`

Do I need to set up some base URL thing that I missed in the documentation or this is a bug?

Comment: Just tried this myself and I did not recieve this error. Can you reproduce it in  a really small example?

Answer (score 0):

Either your code or React is somewhere trying to insert a `http://...` URL into the history that causes this security violation (that's what the error means).

The URL argument to `pushState` should be relative to the current page, or or an absolute URL in your own domain. You can't push state cross-domain - it would be a major security flaw.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) says:

> The new history entry's URL is given by this parameter. Note that the browser won't attempt to load this URL after a call to pushState(), but it might attempt to load the URL later, for instance after the user restarts her browser. The new URL does not need to be absolute; if it's relative, it's resolved relative to the current URL. The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise, pushState() will throw an exception. This parameter is optional; if it isn't specified, it's set to the document's current URL.